# Aspect Ratio of imges are missing when displaying multiple textures on openGL control - OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, shader, opentk

I can display three textures equally on an OpenGL control using below code. OpenGL control is placed on bottom of screen (with height is half of the screen height and width is equal to screen width) . But it seems aspect ratio of images are missing in OpenGL Control. 
Major part of my code are pasted here. Can you please suggest what is causing the issue ?

```
this.glControl1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
this.glControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 412);
this.glControl1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.glControl1.Name = "glControl1";
this.glControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(469, 285);
this.glControl1.TabIndex = 8;
this.glControl1.VSync = false;

 float[] vertices = {
            // Left bottom triangle
            -1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, 1f, 0f,
            // Right top triangle
            1f, 1f, 0f,
           -1f, 1f, 0f,
           -1f, -1f, 0f
    };
    int texSizeLoc;
    int texSize1Loc;
    int texSize2Loc;

 public PlaywithTripleCam()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(PlaywithTripleCam_SizeChanged);
        //ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        //ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
          ScreenWidth = this.Width;
          ScreenHeight = this.Height;
          screenaspectratio =(float) ScreenWidth /(float) ScreenHeight;
        //code for showing camera  device list in three combo box
    }

private void TripleCam_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   glControl1.Width = this.Width;
   glControl1.Height = this.Height / 2;
}
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        StartPlaying();  
        GL.ClearColor(Color.MidnightBlue);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        TexUtil.InitTexturing();
        GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);
        GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Lequal);
        GL.ColorMaterial(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, ColorMaterialParameter.AmbientAndDiffuse);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactor.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactor.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        GL.Ext.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, 0); // render per default onto screen, not some FBO

        glControl1.Resize += new EventHandler(glControl1_Resize);
        glControl1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(glControl1_Paint);
        Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
        // Ensure that the viewport and projection matrix are set correctly.
        glControl1_Resize(glControl1, EventArgs.Empty);

    }
    private void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (glControl1.IsIdle)
        {
            Render();

        }
    }
    public void Render()
    {
        GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0); // use the visible framebuffer
        if (videoFrame != null)
            lock (videoFrame)
            {
                if (videoTexture != -1)
                GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref videoTexture);
                videoTexture = LoadTexture(videoFrame);
                videoFrame.Dispose();
                videoFrame = null;
            }
        GC.Collect();
        if (videoFrame2 != null)
            lock (videoFrame2)
            {
                if (videoTexture2 != -1)
                GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref videoTexture2);
                videoTexture2 = LoadTexture(videoFrame2);
                videoFrame2.Dispose();
                videoFrame2 = null;
            }
        GC.Collect();
        if (videoFrame3!= null)
            lock (videoFrame3)
            {
                if (videoTexture3 != -1)
                GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref videoTexture3);
                videoTexture3 = LoadTexture(videoFrame3);
                videoFrame3.Dispose();
                videoFrame3 = null;
            }
        GC.Collect();
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        DrawImage(videoTexture, videoTexture2, videoTexture3);
    }
    private void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
        varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;                
     void main() {
     vTexCoordIn=( a_position.xy+1)/2;
     gl_Position = vec4(a_position,1);
      }");
     GL.CompileShader(vertShader);

        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"
        uniform sampler2D sTexture;
        uniform sampler2D sTexture1;
        uniform sampler2D sTexture2;
        uniform vec2 sTexSize;
        uniform vec2 sTexSize1;
        uniform vec2 sTexSize2;

        varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;
        void main ()
        {                                               
  vec2 vTexCoord=vec2(vTexCoordIn.x,vTexCoordIn.y);
  if ( vTexCoord.x < 1.0/3.0 )
{
    vec2 uv = vec2(vTexCoord.x * 3.0, vTexCoord.y);
    uv.y *= sTexSize.x / sTexSize.y;
    if (uv.y > 1.0)
        discard;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, uv);
}
else if ( vTexCoord.x >= 1.0/3.0 && vTexCoord.x < 2.0/3.0 )
{
    vec2 uv = vec2(1.0-(vTexCoord.x * 3.0 - 1.0), vTexCoord.y);
    uv.y *= sTexSize1.x / sTexSize1.y;
    if (uv.y > 1.0)
        discard;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture1, uv);
}
else if ( vTexCoord.x >= 2.0/3.0 )
{
    vec2 uv = vec2(vTexCoord.x * 3.0 - 2.0, vTexCoord.y);
    uv.y *= sTexSize2.x / sTexSize2.y;
    if (uv.y > 1.0)
        discard;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture2, uv);
}}");
       GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
     }
    public void DrawImage(int image, int image1,int image2)
    {
        GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height / 2));
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation1, 0);
        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture1);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image1);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation2, 1);
        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture2);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image2);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation3, 2);

       if(videoFrame !=null )
        {
            float texW = videoFrame.Width;
            float texH = videoFrame.Height;
            GL.Uniform2(texSizeLoc, texW, texH);

        }

        if (videoFrame2 != null)
        {

            float tex1W = videoFrame2.Width;
            float tex1H = videoFrame2.Height;
            GL.Uniform2(texSize1Loc, tex1W, tex1H);
        }
        if (videoFrame3 != null)
        {
            float tex2W = videoFrame3.Width;
            float tex2H = videoFrame3.Height;
            GL.Uniform2(texSize2Loc, tex2W, tex2H);

        }

        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
        GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(1920, 0, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
        GL.Vertex3(1920, 1080, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 1080, 0);
        GL.End();
        RunShaders();
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.PopMatrix();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PopMatrix();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
        System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();
        glControl1.SwapBuffers();
    }
    private void RunShaders()
    {
        GL.UseProgram(program);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / 3);
        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
        System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
    private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Render();
    }
    private void glControl1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Init();
    }
    private void Init()
    {
        CreateShaders();
        CreateProgram();
        InitBuffers();
    }
    private void CreateProgram()
    {
        program = GL.CreateProgram();
        GL.AttachShader(program, vertShader);
        GL.AttachShader(program, fragShader);
        GL.LinkProgram(program);
    }
    private void InitBuffers()
    {
        buffer = GL.GenBuffer();
        positionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        positionLocation1 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture");
        positionLocation2 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture1");
        positionLocation3 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture2");

        texSizeLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexSize");
        texSize1Loc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexSize1");
        texSize2Loc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexSize2");

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

    }
    public int LoadTexture(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        int tex = -1;
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);
            GL.GenTextures(1, out tex);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);
            bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
            BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
        }
        return tex;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the aspect ratio for each texture separately. Add 3 uniform variables with the textures sizes and multiply the aspect ratio to the *v* respectively *v* component of the texture coordinate.
Further you should discard fragments which are out of the bounds of the texture, this can be done by the [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) keyword:

```c
uniform sampler2D sTexture;
uniform sampler2D sTexture1;
uniform sampler2D sTexture2;

uniform vec2 sTexSize;
uniform vec2 sTexSize1;
uniform vec2 sTexSize2;

varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;

void main ()
{
    vec2 vTexCoord=vec2(vTexCoordIn.x,vTexCoordIn.y);

    if ( vTexCoord.x < 1.0/3.0 )
    {
        vec2 uv = vec2(vTexCoord.x * 3.0, vTexCoord.y);
        uv.y *= sTexSize.x / sTexSize.y;
        if (uv.y > 1.0)
            discard;
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, uv);
    }
    else if ( vTexCoord.x >= 1.0/3.0 && vTexCoord.x < 2.0/3.0 )
    {
        vec2 uv = vec2(1.0-(vTexCoord.x * 3.0 - 1.0), vTexCoord.y);
        uv.y *= sTexSize1.x / sTexSize1.y;
        if (uv.y > 1.0)
            discard;
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture1, uv);
    }
    else if ( vTexCoord.x >= 2.0/3.0 )
    {
        vec2 uv = vec2(vTexCoord.x * 3.0 - 2.0, vTexCoord.y);
        uv.y *= sTexSize2.x / sTexSize2.y;
        if (uv.y > 1.0)
            discard;
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture2, uv);
    }
}
```

Sst the values of the uniforms by [`GL.Uniform2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.graphics.es20.gl.uniform2):

```cs
texSizeLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexSize");
texSize1Loc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexSize1");
texSize2Loc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexSize2");
```

```cs
float texW = ...;
float texH = ...;
GL.GetUniform2(texSizeLoc, texW, texH);

float tex1W = ...;
float tex1H = ...;
GL.GetUniform2(texSize1Loc, tex1W, tex1H);

float tex2W = ...;
float tex2H = ...;
GL.GetUniform2(texSize2Loc, tex2W, tex2H);
```

Comment: Tried as above. Please see my edited question and resulted screen shot.

Comment: when trying with new shader code with discard , initially gets a fully blurred screen. and after some time each texture comes with  a delay one by one as int the screen shot with a clear color - blue at top. aspect ratio seems getting correct now

Comment: Also there is getting blurred area before loading textures. It takes time to load texture. Is it because I'm checking  if(videoFrame !=null )
        {
            float texW = videoFrame.Width;
            float texH = videoFrame.Height;
            GL.Uniform2(texSizeLoc, texW, texH);

        } this condition?

Comment: Is there any way to set the glcontrol size , and viewport size without lose aspect ratio of texture? seems calculating GL.GetUniform2(texSizeLoc, texW, texH); and assign its value to shader with if loop takes long time. so that getting blurred image initially

Comment: when loading the texture first time, gets a blurred screen with width of screen and half/2 height of screen. and after some time getting three textures with assigned height and width without losing aspect ratio . Can I resolve the appearing of blurred screen initially?